# android checkbox in custom adapter for show cab

Tags: android, checkbox, android-adapter

I've tried to implement contextual action bar(cab) using custom adapter.
First, I made simple `ListView` with cab and it worked.
Second, I tried to make custom adapter contains `CheckBox` and `TextView`.
`CheckBox` for cab, but it didn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("1");
    arr.add("2");
    arr.add("3");
    arr.add("4");
    arr.add("5");
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    lv1.setAdapter(new Adapters(this, R.layout.item, arr));
    lv1.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());
}

private class Adapters extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> arr;
    CheckBox cb;
    int position;
    ViewGroup parent;

    public Adapters(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.arr = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setText(arr.get(position));
        cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.position = position;
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

}

private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        setSubtitle(mode);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
            int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        setSubtitle(mode);
    }

    private void setSubtitle(ActionMode mode) {
        final int checkedCount = lv1.getCheckedItemCount();
        switch (checkedCount) {
            case 0:
                mode.setSubtitle(null);
                break;
            case 1:
                mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                break;
            default:
                mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " items selected");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is not changed `CheckBox`.
I really want to know about this,
Couldn't found any similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in fact, that adding **focusable** elements (like **CheckBox** or **Button**) disables the ability to click the overall list item and their focusability has to be disabled. You should not add any clickable flags to the main layout either.

Set **focusable** to false for your **checkbox** in xml

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my problem is not like that.
I added **focusable** and can click checkbox.
and when i added `((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, true);`
CheckBox isn't changing.